# HTTPS doesn`t work on ODIN-W2

Tags: ssl, networking, https, tls1.2, mbed

I try to build HTTPS example on ODIN W2 with mbedOS and got the next problem:

```
Connecting to os.mbed.com:443
Starting the TLS handshake...
mbedtls_ssl_handshake() failed: -0x2700 (-9984): X509 - Certificate verification failed, e.g. CRL, CA or signature check failed
```

Error flag sets in file x509_crt.c, line 1925:

```
if( x509_profile_check_pk_alg( profile, child->sig_pk ) != 0 )
    *flags |= MBEDTLS_X509_BADCERT_BAD_PK;
```

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: Can you try this against httpbin.org (the second example in https_example.cpp)? I have seen some issues against os.mbed.com where the Mbed TLS config is not loading the right cypher suite, but have not pinpointed the issue yet.